# Predict value in python

Tags: python, regression, predict

I have a device that periodically sends data in the cloud consisting of pairs (timestamp, battery level) and I need to estimate the remaining battery time using python. For example, if battery level is 80%, python script uses data in the cloud to make a prediction of the remaining battery time.
Also, as you can see from the picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WafRD.png), I know what is the progress of the battery drain (x axis of chart represents the seconds elapsed when the device is turned on).

I am just a beginner and I tried with polynomial regression of scikit-learn. Following a tutorial, I wrote this function:

```
#x_energy and y_time are list
def predict(x_energy, y_time):
   from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
   import numpy as np

   X = np.array(x_energy) [:, np.newaxis]
   Y = np.array(y_time)

   pr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
   quadratic = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
   X_quad = quadratic.fit_transform(X)

   X_fit = np.arange(0, max(X), 1)[:, np.newaxis]
   pr.fit(X_quad, Y)
   y_quad_fit = pr.predict(quadratic.fit_transform(X_fit))

   return y_quad_fit[0]
```

but I did not have satisfactory results. This image is an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OETJK.png. I have to reduce as much as possible the distance between the prediction (blue line) and the correct remaining time (red line).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what do you mean when you say "python script uses data in the cloud"?

Comment: When I want to know the remaining time, I run the python script which gets data from cloud and estimates a value. Logically, when I ask the remaining time at time t (where battery is at 80%, for example), there are information about the battery only from the start to time t in the cloud

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what cloud?

Comment: If what you want is an equation for "remaining time = f(current charge)" then X is percent charge and Y is remaining time. So when percent charge is zero, remaining time should also be zero, and the graph you posted does not look like that.

Comment: @MattR the battery is used to power an Arduino that collects data from sensors and battery, and posts them into the cloud (in particular, ThingSpeak). But the cloud has nothing to do with my problem. What I need is an equation like "remaining time = f(current charge)", as said by James Phillips, or an algorithm that uses data available to make a prediction

Comment: @JamesPhillips yes, I need an equation like that. In the graph, x axis represents time. In particular, it shows how many seconds have elapsed since the device was powered on. You can consider them as timestamps: at hour 3:20 PM, battery charge was 87%.

Comment: I understand. My point is that plotting the data in the form that you would actually want to be fitted might be easier to work with than a plot using the timestamps.

Comment: @JamesPhillips ah, ok! I added the chart and the code I used.

Comment: Numpy includes a polynomial fitting routine - the Numpy documentation is here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html with examples at the bottom of the page.